# IQueryable to IQueryable<T>

Tags: linq, entity-framework

is it possibile convert an IQueryable object to IQueryable where T is a mapped entity? (T will be a POCO class).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how you get the non generic `IQueryable`?

Comment: I don't know if this will help but I went the other way.  An IQueryable of Entities to an IQueryable of Objects using an extension method.  I blogged about it here: https://webdevschool.iimagine-websolutions.com/book-1-chapter-7-mod-23

Answer (score 14):

Just [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301460.aspx) it.  Assuming it is a queryable of the same type.  Otherwise you could use the [`OfType<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) filtering method to filter out items of a certain type.

```
IQueryable query = ...;
IQueryable<MyType> x = query.Cast<MyType>();  // assuming the queryable is of `MyType` objects
IQueryable<MyDerivedType> y = query.OfType<MyDerivedType>(); // filter out objects derived from `MyType` (`MyDerivedType`)
```

---

However in your case, you say that you are using Dynamic LINQ and doing a dynamic projection.  Consider this completely made up query:

```
var query = dc.SomeTable
              .Where("SomeProperty = \"foo\"")
              .Select("new (SomeProperty, AnotherProperty)");
```

It results in a query of type `IQueryable`.  You cannot cast this to a query of a specific type `IQueryable<T>` after all, what is `T`?  What the Dynamic LINQ library does is creates a type that derives from `DynamicCass`.  You could cast to `IQueryable<DynamicClass>` (`query.Cast<DynamicClass>()`) but you will not have access to the properties so it's moot.

Really the only nice option you have is to use `dynamic` to access these properties in this case.

```
foreach (dynamic x in query)
{
    string someProperty = x.SomeProperty;
    int anotherProperty = x.AnotherProperty;
    // etc...
}
```

If you want to convert this to a query of your POCO objects, you'll have to do the conversion as a separate step but using LINQ to Objects.

```
IEnumerable<SomePoco> query =
    dc.SomeTable
      .Where("SomeProperty = \"foo\"")
      .Select("new (SomeProperty, AnotherProperty)")
      .Cast<DynamicObject>().AsEnumerable().Cast<dynamic>()
      .Select(x => new SomePoco
      {
          SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty,
          AnotherProperty = x.AnotherProperty,
      });
```

If you must have an `IQueryable<T>`, then you should not use dynamic projections in the first place.

```
IQueryable<SomePoco> query =
    dc.SomeTable
      .Where("SomeProperty = \"foo\"")
      .Select(x => new SomePoco
      {
          SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty,
          AnotherProperty = x.AnotherProperty,
      });
```

---

Seeing as how the cast is not working for LINQ to Entities, then I suppose the only option you have to get a strongly type collection of your POCO objects is to break this out into a loop.

```
var query = dc.SomeTable
              .Where("SomeProperty = \"foo\"")
              .Select("new (SomeProperty, AnotherProperty)");

var result = new List<SomePoco>();
foreach (dynamic x in query)
{
    result.Add(new SomePoco
    {
        SomeProperty = x.SomeProperty,
        AnotherProperty = x.AnotherProperty,
    });
}
```

Comment: I get System.Exception: cannot execute cast of type .. Linq To Entities supported cast for primitive type only..

Comment: All what I need is achieve an IQueryable<T> starting from dynamics linq to entity:
 
step 1: I've something like this -> var query1 = myCtx.Where(..lambda);

step 2: I must select just some field (I cannot use lambda here), so: 
var query2 = query1.Select("myFiled1, myFiled2);

step 2 is achievable through ScottGu's System.Linq.Dynamic.dll library.

problem here: the step 2 return an IQueryable, while I need to IQueryable<T> where T is my POCO class.

I not able to convert..I always get exception during conversion..

Comment: @Alex: That is the sort if information that would have been useful when you asked the question.  Well in that case you cannot cast to a specific type since you project to a dynamic type and technically, you don't know the type a compile time.  You can cast to a `DynamicClass` however since that's the type those objects derive from though you will not be able to access to the fields directly unless you use `dynamic` variables.

Comment: Please, could you give me same example? I'm not sure to have understand your answer..

Comment: @Alex: I've extended my answer.  Hopefully it will be more clear now.

Comment: ehmm....i tried your example, ok, IEnumerable<> it's ok, but I have got always same exception "linq to entities supports cast for primitive type only". You example doesn't work..

Comment: @Alex: Try changing the first cast to `.Cast<object>()` and see if that works.  If not, then you may have to break this out into a loop instead.

Comment: It's the same. Nothing works fine. Linq to Entities doesn't support any cast type. I'm hopeless.

Comment: Yes, now it's works fine, but my objectContext cannot tracing any changes apported to list, so it's useless.. :(

Comment: @Alex: I don't know what else to say then.  As far as I know, the changes you make to the entities should go through and won't be "detached" just because it's not in an `IQueryable<T>`.  If it's not working for you at this point, then I can't really help you here then.

Comment: In your last example you simply create many instance of SomePoco class and add its to result List, but how can objectContext knows of them?? So whatever modify apported to result list will be useless. the result var is "stand-alone". Have you understand me?

Comment: @Alex: Ah I see what you mean.  Maybe you should not be doing any projections at all.  Leave it as `dc.SomeTable.Where("SomeProperty = \"foo\"")` so you get the objects come directly from the table.  If their types are not the POCO objects you want, then you'll have to deal with it.  You can't expect to be able to make changes to objects that are meant only for getting values out to be used to make changes.  At least that's how I understand it.